# How to exchange data in python flask-html server(pythonanywhere) to AndroidStudio application?

Tags: android, python, flask

My server is python flask server in Pycharm, and databases are simple local folder's text files.

I used Pythonanywhere to automatically operate my server whenever.
And now, I see my pythonanywhere website is operate well, but it cannot exchange just a number or text data in source code to flutter application.
How I exchange data? (I don't use Firebase, MySQL, etc.)

> flask http server(Pycharm) <data<->data> Androidstudio flutter application
>   flask http server(Pythonanywhere) <Failed> flutter application

I saw 'https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/' and 'https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/' so many times because when I asked it problem, pythonanywhere always said see it pages but it wasn't useful.
I set `wsgi`, environment file, and website options successfully in pythonanywhere.

There is a error log every time, but it isn't effect my anything:

```
2019-06-06 16:08:45,940: Error running WSGI application
2019-06-06 16:08:45,948: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'
2019-06-06 16:08:45,948:   File "/var/www/trees2001_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 104, in <module>
2019-06-06 16:08:45,948:     from flask_app import app
2019-06-06 16:08:45,948: ***************************************************
2019-06-06 16:08:45,949: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-06-06 16:08:45,949: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-06-06 16:08:45,949: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
```

And it disappeared when I changed code :

```
from flask_app import app' -> 'from flask_app import app as application')
```

`flask http server` in pythonanywhere /home/trees2001/mysite/flask_app.py :

```py
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os.path
import datetime

def getInfos(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    # id, pw = [], []
    infos = []
    for line in lines:
        t = line.split(':')
        infos.append((t[0], t[1]))
        # id.append(t[0])
        # pw.append(t[1])

    return infos

def findId(filename, text):
    infos = getInfos(filename)
    for id in infos:
        if str(id[0]) == text:
            return True
    return False

def checkInfo(filename, id, pw):
    infos = getInfos(filename)
    for info in infos:
        if info[0] == id and info[1][:-1] == pw: # info[1]->비밀번호. 마지막의 '\n' 제거. Password. remove last '\n'.
            return True
    return False

def writeInfo(filename, id, pw):
    f = open(filename, 'a')
    f.write('{}:{}\n'.format(id, pw))
    f.close()

def readJustLine(filename, i):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    if i+1 > len(lines):
        return 'error\n'
    return lines[i]

def writeString(filename, string):
    f = open(filename, 'a')
    f.write('{}\n'.format(string))
    f.close()

def makeFile(filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename): # 파일 확인 check file
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.close()

def saveId(filename, id):
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(id)
    f.close()

filepath = '/home/trees2001/mysite/info_test.txt'
# path_filename = 'c:/test/path_test.txt'
basic_path = '/home/trees2001/mysite/'
sIdPath = basic_path + 'name4Id.txt'
# fileSavePath = 'C:/Users/Deep-Learning/PycharmProjects/photo_cloud_flask/uploads/'
fileSavePath = '/home/trees2001/mysite/uploads/'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/home/trees2001/mysite/uploads/'
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 100 * 1024 * 1024
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_PATH'] = 100 * 1024 * 1024

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def route():

    return '<h1>Deployed</h1>'

@app.route('/Reg', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # 회원가입 버튼 Register button
def register():
    id = request.form['id']
    pw = request.form['pw']
    print('id: {}, pw: {}'.format(id, pw))

    # if findId(filepath, id) == True:
    #     return 'false'

    # writeInfo(filepath, id, pw)
    # # return 'true'
    return '<h1>{}</h1>'.format(id)
    # return '<h1>ABGC</h1>'

@app.route('/Login', methods=['POST']) # 로그인 버튼 Login button
def login():
    id = request.form['id']
    pw = request.form['pw']

    if checkInfo(filepath, id, pw) == False:
        return 'false'

    # newPath = id + '_path'
    # filepath = makeFile(newPath)
    # filepath = newPath
    makeFile('{0}path_{1}.txt'.format(basic_path, id))

    saveId(sIdPath, id)
    return 'true'

@app.route('/fileUpload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    # if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['file']
    r = readJustLine(sIdPath, 0)

    # 저장할 경로 + 파일명 saving path + filename
    f.save(fileSavePath + r + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg'))

    return 'true'

@app.route('/Path', methods = ['POST'])
def savePath():
    path = request.form['path']
    path_filename = request.form['path_filename']
    writeString(path_filename, path)
    return 'true'

@app.route('/PathList', methods=['POST'])
def pathList():
    n = request.form['n']
    path_filename = request.form['path_filename']

    if n != '':
        check = readJustLine(path_filename, int(n))[:-1]
        if 'error' in check:
            return 'false'
        return check
    return ['']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Androidstudio flutter application's one sending funcion :

```dart
Future<String> postReply() async {
    if(id == null || pw == null)
      return '';

    var addr = gServerIp + ((mKind == Datakind.REG) ? 'Reg' : 'Login');
    var response = await http.post(addr, body: {'id':id, 'pw':pw});

    if(response.statusCode == 200)
      return response.body;

    throw Exception('데이터 수신 실패'); // Data didn't send
  }
```

I tested server by return data, like `<h1>Deployed</h1>` or `{}.format(id)`.
I think it will operate well, but only website.
It can return just h1 line on website, but it cannot exchange to my flutter application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the URL you're constructing (the `addr =` line) is actually a valid URL that is served by your web app and, if it is, check the content of the response that you're getting back in `postReply` to see what is happening on the server.